# different logic for iOS and OS X ? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData swift

Tags: ios, json, xcode, macos, swift

Help me plz. I have JSON and 2 application 1 for MacOS, and 1 for iOS

Both applications use 1 code fragment in func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!)

Why different results? self.data is good

**MacOS**

```
func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
    var err: NSError?
    let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var jsonResult: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    ParserCreater.createWithJSON(jsonResult, pathDir:pathDir.path!, jsonUrl: tfURL.stringValue)
    self.data = NSMutableData()
}
```

result:

```
Printing description of str:
{"title":"Заголовок","margin": [1, 2, 3, 4],"rect1": [0, 0, 100, 50],"color1": "#00FF44","color2": "#FFF","point": [0, 100],"size": [500, 600]}
Printing description of jsonResult:
([String : AnyObject]) jsonResult = {
  [0] = {
    key = "color1"
    value = (instance_type = Builtin.RawPointer = 0x3434464630302375)
  }
  [1] = {
    key = "title"
    value = (instance_type = Builtin.RawPointer = 0x00006000000455e0 -> 0x00007fff767c7538 (void *)0x00007fff767c74e8: __NSCFString)
  }
  [2] = {
    key = "rect1"
    value = (instance_type = Builtin.RawPointer = 0x00006000004430f0 -> 0x00007fff767c7dd0 (void *)0x00007fff767c7f10: __NSArrayM)
  }
  [3] = {
    key = "size"
    value = (instance_type = Builtin.RawPointer = 0x0000600000646570 -> 0x00007fff767c7dd0 (void *)0x00007fff767c7f10: __NSArrayM)
  }
  [4] = {
    key = "margin"
    value = (instance_type = Builtin.RawPointer = 0x0000600000044fe0 -> 0x00007fff767c7dd0 (void *)0x00007fff767c7f10: __NSArrayM)
  }
  [5] = {
    key = "point"
    value = (instance_type = Builtin.RawPointer = 0x000060000024b2b0 -> 0x00007fff767c7dd0 (void *)0x00007fff767c7f10: __NSArrayM)
  }
  [6] = {
    key = "color2"
    value = (instance_type = Builtin.RawPointer = 0x0000004646462345)
  }
}
```

**iOS**

```
func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
    var err: NSError?
    let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var jsonResult: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    self.data = NSMutableData()
}
```

result:

```
Printing description of str:
{"title":"Заголовок","margin": [1, 2, 3, 4],"rect1": [0, 0, 100, 50],"color1": "#00FF44","color2": "#FFF","point": [0, 100],"size": [500, 600]}
Printing description of jsonResult:
([String : AnyObject]) jsonResult = {}
```

Comment: So, what does `err` tell you???

Comment: err = nil;
i think is debug error, parsing is complete

Comment: I seriously doubt that `data` was as claimed, JSONObjectWithData returned nothing, and the error parm is nil.  You need to get your story straight.

Answer (score 0):

No error in parsing!
Error in the display of content, as it turned out, all values in the variable jsonResult there. With key, you can access them, but for some reason it is  not shown in the description